# How much wind is too much wind on a sandy beach?

Tags: weather-and-climate, beaches

I was looking at beaches meteo forecast. They announced some wind from 2 m/s to 7 m/s depending on the beach. I have a hard time to realize how unpleasant is such wind. I aim to read and don't want sand flying in my eyes, have too much sand in my book or on my towel.

Can you please give me an opinion (descriptive scale) of how unpleasant is different wind speed on a sandy beach? It probably depends on the activity, on whether one can hide behind a log or not and maybe on the equipment.

Comment: Reminded me of a beach in Fuerteventura, where you felt like standing inside a giant sand blaster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't attest to what your personal taste in wind is, but if you look at the [Beaufort scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale) 2 m/s is described as a `light breeze`,

For Sea:

> Small wavelets, still short but more pronounced; crests have a glassy
>   appearance and do not break

For land:

> Wind felt on exposed skin. Leaves rustle. Wind vanes begin to move.

While 7 m/s is the top end of a `moderate breeze`

For Sea:

> Small waves with breaking crests. Fairly frequent whitecaps.

For land:

> Dust and loose paper raised. Small branches begin to move.

So I'd say that at the low end of 2 m/s you'll be fine, but you may face sand starting to blow about at the upper end of 7 m/s.  Of course that is going to depend on the type of sand (fine vs coarse), the geography of the beach (open vs protected) and the direction of the wind (on-shore vs off-shore vs along the beach)

And add into that other factors such as is the day sunny or cloudy, air temperature and humidity will change how you experience the local weather.

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I went to the beach yesterday, and the winds were 15 miles per hour. That didn't sound like much, but we were constantly blasted by sand the whole time we were there. It stuck to our sunscreened skin and made us very uncomfortable.

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer.  15 miles/hour is 7 metres/sec, so fits in with the description given in the previous answer

Comment: I agree with @Doc. This doesn't provide a complete answer so much as one datum; better suited for a comment.